# "consisting of" or "that consist of" in this context

Tags: sentence-construction, participle-phrases

A book defines **sonnet** as:

> A lyric poem **consisting of** a single stanza of fourteen iambic pentameter lines...

But if I rewrite it as:

> A lyric poem **that consists of** a single stanza of fourteen iambic pentameter lines...

The first definition is using a **participial phrase.**

My question is that whether they are **interchangeable** or not?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is that whether they are interchangeable or not?

Yes, they are (in this case).

> A sonnet is a lyric poem *consisting of* a single stanza of fourteen iambic pentameter lines ...
>
> A sonnet is a lyric poem *that consists of* a single stanza of fourteen iambic pentameter lines ...
>
> A sonnet is a lyric poem *which consists of* a single stanza of fourteen iambic pentameter lines ...

What you are essentially doing here is expanding the participle phrase (-ing, -ed) into a relative clause (that, which, who). You could also do the opposite: reduce the relative clause into a participle phrase. Participle phrases use fewer words to say the same thing or provide the same information as a relative clause.

If space is limited or there is a word limit (e.g., in a newspaper article) a participle phrase may be preferred.  There is also the matter of style and choice. Besides those, I can't think of any other reason why one would be preferred over the other.